# What value will be replaced by question mark?

Tags: mathematics

I can't find any answer
The options are:
(a)18.
(B) 16.
(C)10.
(D)12!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think it is

> B (16)

Because:

> Every line goes the first number / 2 + 2nd number * 2 = third number. Which means the last line is 12/2+5*2=16 (B) 
> $6/2+11*2=25$ 
> $48/2+6*2=16$ 
> $12/2+5*2=16$